# Autoincrement Value in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

What's the best way, or, how would you do to have a field in PHP+SQL formatted as AB00000 where the first inserted should be AB00001 and so on. I have a web page in PHP+SQL to create a form and insert it into a table wich one of the columns is the "reference_nr" and my whole code is already made using the ID (AutoIncrement) so I can't use that for that table.

What I would need is something that would always write the last used maybe to another different table and before INSERT into form's table I would SELECT the last value and increment + 1 and INSERT with the result of that math operation.

- Do I need another table or can I select directly from the form's table?
- Do you think it give me problems if two persons try to INSERT the
  form at the same time?

Comment: Maybe use a standard auto-increment column in the backing storage but simply format the *display* of the identifier to the given width with the given prefix?

Comment: Or use 2 queries: 1st) INSERT user in db and get the id ($mysqli->insert_id); 2nd) UPDATE user to give him the correct AB00... based on the id.

Comment: mysql can only create plain integer autoincrement values. it won't create composite values/strings for you. but you COULD use a post-insert trigger to create that composite value in some other field in the table.

Comment: To answer your question about two people inserting at same time you may want to look at transactions [mysql transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html)

Comment: Is your problem how to get an autoincrement value for a string column with prefix like AB00000? Autoincrement fields are only numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is how to get an autoincrement value for a string column with prefix like AB00000, autoincrement fields are only numeric. 
If the field have a fixed format you can create a plain insert using the id value from:

```
SELECT CONCAT('AB', LPAD( MAX(SUBSTRING(id,3)+1 ,5,'0') from table
```

And use this value directly in your insert to avoid transaction problems

Answer (score 1):

SQL brings that already with it:

Use the SQL-Function LAST_INSERT_ID() similar to the example in the source page I linked you below. Let's assume table foo has an auto-increment field "id":

```
INSERT INTO 
    foo (auto, text, somevalue)
VALUES
    (NULL,'text', 2);         # id was generated hoer
```

Then you do:

```
UPDATE 
    foo
SET 
     somevalue = somevalue + 1
WHERE
     id = LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html